# Moving from C# on Windows to Objective-C on Mac

Tags: c#, objective-c

I'm going to be getting my first Mac computer soon, and I want to learn Objective-C. I already have experience in C#, and I've already started learning C++, but absolutely everything in Objective-C confuses me, including memory management. Do you have any tips on moving from C# to Objective-C? I've read that I should learn C++ before learning Objective-C, but so far C++ looks a lot like C# which looks very different from Objective-C.

**Edit: For the people trying to learn from this question, I HIGHLY recommend buying the "Learn Objective-C on the Mac" book by Apress. It's very well written if you're coming from a C-like language (like C, C++, C#, Java, PHP, etc.)**

Comment: I tried the exact same thing and it's incredibly difficult to grasp, at least for me. So, considering that Xcode is already a paid program, you might want to try MonoTouch, which translates .NET into native iOS code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure XCode is free.

Comment: It's free with a developer account and pay for everyone else (e.g. on the Mac App Store). However, the price is less than $5. Also, Apple announced to make it completely free for everyone again soon at WWDC2011.

Comment: +1 for getting a Mac  :)

Comment: @Raphael - SO is not a site for you to express your platform preferences. Leave it on Engadget, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Learn Objective-C directly. No need to learn C++ first. The two are completely different in all aspects that seem to confuse you.

Also understand that for writing functional applications on the Mac, your focus will be more on learning and understanding the Cocoa API than Objective-C itself. Objective-C can be picked up in an afternoon by an experienced programmer. Cocoa takes more time.

For the purpose of learning Cocoa (and Objective-C at the same time), I recommend "[Learn Cocoa on the Mac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218592)". It's the book most developers on our team used to get started.

If your focus is on iOS development instead, you'll need to learn Cocoa-Touch. I learned it using [Beginning iPhone 4 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023024X), which I can recommend.

Comment: Good answer; but both links are for the same book.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Just fixed the links.

Comment: I might also get into iOS development, so would you recommend reading "Learn Cocoa on the Mac" before "Beginning iPhone 4 Development"?

Comment: If you are interested in both, I recommend learning iOS development first as it forces you to study and understand memory management. After you understood the Cocoa-Touch concepts you can easily learn Cocoa in less than a week (speaking from a "full time learning at work" perspective).

Comment: It's worth noting that memory management is becoming less of an issue now. It isn't that hard to begin with (far from the malloc/free pure C world). On the Mac you have access to garbage collection, and on the newest versions of iOS and OSX you will have ARC, which does most of the same stuff but at compile time. I would say learn Mac dev first, as there are fewer hassles when getting started. Also, I would recommend on holding off getting your Mac until Lion is released, sometime later this month.

Comment: Martin raises a valid point. ARC will make manual memory management obsolete on iOS 4+ and OSX 10.6+ in the near future. Without the drawbacks of GC. ARC automates retain/release memory management. In the end, it's a preference choice you'll have to make. Understanding how retain/release works will help you better understand how your code works (and will be mandatory to deploy to iOS versions before 4.x). But to just get started, it is no longer mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

Josh Smith of joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com made the switch to iOS a couple of years ago.

He just published a book: ***iOS Programming for .NET Developers***

Here is the write up on it:

This book is a field guide for .NET developers exploring the foreign world of native iOS programming. It explains the iOS development platform by comparing and contrasting it with tools, APIs, and concepts familiar to .NET developers.

The author, Josh Smith, was a Microsoft MVP for four years thanks to his technical and written contributions in the Client Application Development community. He has worked on enterprise iOS applications since 2010. This is the book he wished had existed when he started learning iOS.

Here is the link to his new blog on iOS: [ijoshsmith.com](http://www.ijoshsmith.com)

And his new book: [iosfordotnetdevs.com](http://www.iosfordotnetdevs.com)

Good luck - I have found Objective C to be really weird at first :)